# Lighthouse mutations can't get big string or json

Tags: json, laravel, graphql, lighthouse

When i want to pass a big string like json data i got this error:
"error": "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Can people help me?

**My query:**

```
mutation {

  createReport(
    input: {
      name: "Fds"
      report_category_id: 1
      data: "{\"mainSetting\":{\"reportName\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645 \\u06af\\u0632\\u0627\\u0631\\u0634\",\"database\":{\"id\":495,\"ip_address\":\"192.168.1.100\",\"port\":3355,\"database_name\":\"report_maker_vuejs\",\"database_alias\":\"\\u06af\\u0632\\u0627\\u0631\\u0634 \\u062a\\u0633\\u062a\\u06cc\",\"username\":\"root\",\"is_done\":true,\"created_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:39\"},\"table\":{\"id\":42854,\"database_id\":495,\"title\":\"databases\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:42\",\"has_relation\":null},\"group\":{\"id\":2,\"title\":\"\\u062a\\u062c\\u0627\\u0631\\u062a\",\"icon\":null,\"created_at\":\"1397-12-27 10:32\"}},\"informationSetting\":{\"id\":\"baseTable\",\"tableID\":42854,\"relationID\":0,\"relationName\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0647\",\"allonym\":\"0_42854\",\"name\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"field\":[{\"alias\":\"1212\",\"label\":\"deleted_at\",\"fieldID\":302481,\"allonym\":\"0_42854_302481\",\"id\":\"5mawiacdui3\",\"type\":\"date\",\"table_allonym\":\"0_42854\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0647\",\"table_label\":\"databases\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0633\\u0627\\u062e\\u062a\\u0647 \\u0634\\u062f\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0631\",\"label\":\"created_at\",\"fieldID\":302479,\"allonym\":\"0_42854_302479\",\"id\":\"kg57kl6pl4o\",\"type\":\"date\",\"table_allonym\":\"0_42854\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0647\",\"table_label\":\"databases\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\",\"label\":\"database_alias\",\"fieldID\":302477,\"allonym\":\"0_42854_302477\",\"id\":\"0l7jqq4saad\",\"type\":\"text\",\"table_allonym\":\"0_42854\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0647\",\"table_label\":\"databases\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0631\\u0645\\u0632 \\u0639\\u0628\\u0648\\u0631\",\"label\":\"password\",\"fieldID\":302476,\"allonym\":\"0_42854_302476\",\"id\":\"hdy5cq5ovhc\",\"type\":\"text\",\"table_allonym\":\"0_42854\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0647\",\"table_label\":\"databases\"},{\"alias\":\"565656\",\"label\":\"database_name\",\"fieldID\":302474,\"allonym\":\"0_42854_302474\",\"id\":\"t3q183ysxuf\",\"type\":\"text\",\"table_allonym\":\"0_42854\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0647\",\"table_label\":\"databases\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u06a9\\u0627\\u0631\\u0628\\u0631\",\"label\":\"user_id\",\"fieldID\":302471,\"allonym\":\"0_42854_302471\",\"id\":\"2geqrbmpanb\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"0_42854\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0647\",\"table_label\":\"databases\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647\",\"label\":\"id\",\"fieldID\":302469,\"allonym\":\"0_42854_302469\",\"id\":\"jc1g38813qe\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"0_42854\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0647\",\"table_label\":\"databases\"}],\"condition\":[],\"children\":[{\"id\":\"b7sjqhjlnie\",\"title\":\"tables\",\"tableID\":42868,\"relationID\":17,\"relation\":{\"id\":17,\"name\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0631 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"source_table_id\":42868,\"source_column_id\":302571,\"destination_table_id\":42854,\"destination_column_id\":302469,\"relationPosition\":\"source\"},\"allonym\":\"17_42868\",\"relationName\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0631 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"relationType\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"INNER JOIN\"},\"name\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"field\":[{\"alias\":\"\\u0628\\u0631\\u0648\\u0632 \\u0634\\u062f\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0631\",\"label\":\"updated_at\",\"fieldID\":302577,\"allonym\":\"17_42868_302577\",\"id\":\"iw2rt9yki6\",\"type\":\"date\",\"table_allonym\":\"17_42868\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0631 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"tables\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0646\\u0648\\u0639\",\"label\":\"type\",\"fieldID\":302574,\"allonym\":\"17_42868_302574\",\"id\":\"ar3d8h6im5c\",\"type\":\"text\",\"table_allonym\":\"17_42868\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0631 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"tables\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"label\":\"title\",\"fieldID\":302572,\"allonym\":\"17_42868_302572\",\"id\":\"ms25l7f7x57\",\"type\":\"text\",\"table_allonym\":\"17_42868\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0631 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"tables\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\",\"label\":\"database_id\",\"fieldID\":302571,\"allonym\":\"17_42868_302571\",\"id\":\"1l3fmz7o85x\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"17_42868\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0631 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"tables\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647\",\"label\":\"id\",\"fieldID\":302570,\"allonym\":\"17_42868_302570\",\"id\":\"ivjqjshlt6a\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"17_42868\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0631 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"tables\"}],\"condition\":[],\"children\":[{\"id\":\"t0qk8ktplkq\",\"title\":\"columns\",\"tableID\":42851,\"relation\":{\"id\":18,\"name\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\\u06cc \\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"source_table_id\":42868,\"source_column_id\":302570,\"destination_table_id\":42851,\"destination_column_id\":302444,\"relationPosition\":\"destination\"},\"relationID\":18,\"allonym\":\"18_42851\",\"relationName\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\\u06cc \\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"relationType\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"INNER JOIN\"},\"name\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"field\":[{\"alias\":\"\\u062d\\u0630\\u0641 \\u0634\\u062f\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0631\",\"label\":\"deleted_at\",\"fieldID\":302455,\"allonym\":\"18_42851_302455\",\"id\":\"36ezl5qrv6i\",\"type\":\"date\",\"table_allonym\":\"18_42851\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\\u06cc \\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"columns\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0639\\u0646\\u0648\\u0627\\u0646 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"label\":\"title\",\"fieldID\":302445,\"allonym\":\"18_42851_302445\",\"id\":\"mqmp5harv7\",\"type\":\"text\",\"table_allonym\":\"18_42851\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\\u06cc \\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"columns\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"label\":\"table_id\",\"fieldID\":302444,\"allonym\":\"18_42851_302444\",\"id\":\"7nip8hcxqpp\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"18_42851\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\\u06cc \\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"columns\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"label\":\"id\",\"fieldID\":302443,\"allonym\":\"18_42851_302443\",\"id\":\"3dt8kh0cq6i\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"18_42851\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\\u06cc \\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"table_label\":\"columns\"}],\"condition\":[],\"children\":[{\"id\":\"2mrwumlkff5\",\"title\":\"relations\",\"tableID\":42865,\"relationID\":22,\"relation\":{\"id\":22,\"name\":\"\\u0627\\u0631\\u062a\\u0628\\u0627\\u0637 \\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0645\\u0628\\u062f\\u0627\",\"source_table_id\":42865,\"source_column_id\":302552,\"destination_table_id\":42851,\"destination_column_id\":302443,\"relationPosition\":\"source\"},\"allonym\":\"22_42865\",\"relationName\":\"\\u0627\\u0631\\u062a\\u0628\\u0627\\u0637 \\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0645\\u0628\\u062f\\u0627\",\"relationType\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"INNER JOIN\"},\"name\":\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"field\":[{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"label\":\"source_column_id\",\"fieldID\":302552,\"allonym\":\"22_42865_302552\",\"id\":\"aplwywntg9\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"22_42865\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u0627\\u0631\\u062a\\u0628\\u0627\\u0637 \\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0645\\u0628\\u062f\\u0627\",\"table_label\":\"relations\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645\",\"label\":\"name\",\"fieldID\":302550,\"allonym\":\"22_42865_302550\",\"id\":\"7v2hxg4aau\",\"type\":\"text\",\"table_allonym\":\"22_42865\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u0627\\u0631\\u062a\\u0628\\u0627\\u0637 \\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0645\\u0628\\u062f\\u0627\",\"table_label\":\"relations\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\",\"label\":\"database_id\",\"fieldID\":302549,\"allonym\":\"22_42865_302549\",\"id\":\"hv4g2q10h0w\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"22_42865\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u0627\\u0631\\u062a\\u0628\\u0627\\u0637 \\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0645\\u0628\\u062f\\u0627\",\"table_label\":\"relations\"},{\"alias\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647\",\"label\":\"id\",\"fieldID\":302548,\"allonym\":\"22_42865_302548\",\"id\":\"elig6ymy24v\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"table_allonym\":\"22_42865\",\"table_alias\":\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"relation_title\":\"\\u0627\\u0631\\u062a\\u0628\\u0627\\u0637 \\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0645\\u0628\\u062f\\u0627\",\"table_label\":\"relations\"}],\"condition\":[],\"children\":[]}]}]}],\"title\":\"databases\"},\"formulationSetting\":[],\"fieldTags\":[{\"title\":\"table\",\"label\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"color\":\"#029386\"},{\"title\":\"date\",\"label\":\"\\u062a\\u0627\\u0631\\u06cc\\u062e\",\"color\":\"#a98464\"},{\"title\":\"numeric\",\"label\":\"\\u0639\\u062f\\u062f\",\"color\":\"#93cadc\"},{\"title\":\"text\",\"label\":\"\\u0645\\u062a\\u0646\",\"color\":\"#9b998c\"},{\"title\":\"formula\",\"label\":\"\\u0641\\u0631\\u0645\\u0648\\u0644\",\"color\":\"#efbaec\"},{\"title\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"label\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"color\":\"rgba(39, 224, 198,0.25)\"},{\"title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"label\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"color\":\"rgba(181, 187, 24,0.25)\"},{\"title\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"label\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"color\":\"rgba(116, 111, 177,0.25)\"},{\"title\":\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"label\":\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"color\":\"rgba(65, 113, 242,0.25)\"}],\"sortingSetting\":[{\"id\":\"iird1krc8a\",\"table_alias\":\"0_42854\",\"column_alias\":\"0_42854_302481\",\"column_title\":\"0_42854.deleted_at\",\"alternative_title\":\"1212\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"date\"],\"type\":\"date\",\"icon\":\"CalendarIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"xjpy4yze13f\",\"table_alias\":\"0_42854\",\"column_alias\":\"0_42854_302479\",\"column_title\":\"0_42854.created_at\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0633\\u0627\\u062e\\u062a\\u0647 \\u0634\\u062f\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0631\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"date\"],\"type\":\"date\",\"icon\":\"CalendarIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"fxevzwc2hhn\",\"table_alias\":\"0_42854\",\"column_alias\":\"0_42854_302477\",\"column_title\":\"0_42854.database_alias\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"text\"],\"type\":\"text\",\"icon\":\"FileTextIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":{\"type\":{\"title\":\"Value Range\",\"method\":\"valueRange\"}},\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"},\"haveFilter\":true},{\"id\":\"7zzbhb0dted\",\"table_alias\":\"0_42854\",\"column_alias\":\"0_42854_302476\",\"column_title\":\"0_42854.password\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0631\\u0645\\u0632 \\u0639\\u0628\\u0648\\u0631\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"text\"],\"type\":\"text\",\"icon\":\"FileTextIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"ek00zdrmw0c\",\"table_alias\":\"0_42854\",\"column_alias\":\"0_42854_302474\",\"column_title\":\"0_42854.database_name\",\"alternative_title\":\"565656\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"text\"],\"type\":\"text\",\"icon\":\"FileTextIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"y3o9ntx4czq\",\"table_alias\":\"0_42854\",\"column_alias\":\"0_42854_302471\",\"column_title\":\"0_42854.user_id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u06a9\\u0627\\u0631\\u0628\\u0631\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"92d2mcum8kf\",\"table_alias\":\"0_42854\",\"column_alias\":\"0_42854_302469\",\"column_title\":\"0_42854.id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"txi231u2z\",\"table_alias\":\"17_42868\",\"column_alias\":\"17_42868_302577\",\"column_title\":\"17_42868.updated_at\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0628\\u0631\\u0648\\u0632 \\u0634\\u062f\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0631\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"date\"],\"type\":\"date\",\"icon\":\"CalendarIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":{\"type\":{\"title\":\"Date Range\",\"method\":\"dateRange\"}},\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"},\"haveFilter\":true},{\"id\":\"jkri56axecj\",\"table_alias\":\"17_42868\",\"column_alias\":\"17_42868_302574\",\"column_title\":\"17_42868.type\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0646\\u0648\\u0639\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"text\"],\"type\":\"text\",\"icon\":\"FileTextIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"bnaiauc0trw\",\"table_alias\":\"17_42868\",\"column_alias\":\"17_42868_302572\",\"column_title\":\"17_42868.title\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"text\"],\"type\":\"text\",\"icon\":\"FileTextIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"kg2ke59ib5\",\"table_alias\":\"17_42868\",\"column_alias\":\"17_42868_302571\",\"column_title\":\"17_42868.database_id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":{\"type\":{\"title\":\"Multi Select\",\"method\":\"multiSelect\"},\"table\":{\"id\":42854,\"database_id\":495,\"title\":\"databases\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:42\",\"has_relation\":null},\"field\":{\"id\":302477,\"table_id\":42854,\"title\":\"database_alias\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\",\"data_type\":\"varchar(255)\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"0\",\"is_index\":\"0\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-23 15:15\"},\"fieldID\":{\"id\":302469,\"table_id\":42854,\"title\":\"id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647\",\"data_type\":\"bigint(20) unsigned\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"1\",\"is_index\":\"1\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:40\"},\"children\":{\"id\":\"bht9mrcgwuk\",\"table_alias\":\"18_42851\",\"column_alias\":\"18_42851_302444\",\"column_title\":\"18_42851.table_id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":{\"type\":{\"title\":\"Multi Select\",\"method\":\"multiSelect\"},\"table\":{\"id\":42868,\"database_id\":495,\"title\":\"tables\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:43\",\"has_relation\":null},\"field\":{\"id\":302572,\"table_id\":42868,\"title\":\"title\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"data_type\":\"varchar(255)\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"0\",\"is_index\":\"0\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-23 15:19\"},\"fieldID\":{\"id\":302570,\"table_id\":42868,\"title\":\"id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647\",\"data_type\":\"bigint(20) unsigned\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"1\",\"is_index\":\"1\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:40\"}},\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"},\"haveFilter\":true},\"ForeignKey\":{\"id\":302571,\"table_id\":42868,\"title\":\"database_id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u067e\\u0627\\u06cc\\u06af\\u0627\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\",\"data_type\":\"bigint(20) unsigned\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"0\",\"is_index\":\"1\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:40\"}},\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"},\"haveFilter\":true},{\"id\":\"5ndc98k10mc\",\"table_alias\":\"17_42868\",\"column_alias\":\"17_42868_302570\",\"column_title\":\"17_42868.id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"djt03m6vv7g\",\"table_alias\":\"18_42851\",\"column_alias\":\"18_42851_302455\",\"column_title\":\"18_42851.deleted_at\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u062d\\u0630\\u0641 \\u0634\\u062f\\u0647 \\u062f\\u0631\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"date\"],\"type\":\"date\",\"icon\":\"CalendarIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":{\"type\":{\"title\":\"Date Range\",\"method\":\"dateRange\"}},\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"},\"haveFilter\":true},{\"id\":\"y0juvas87g\",\"table_alias\":\"18_42851\",\"column_alias\":\"18_42851_302445\",\"column_title\":\"18_42851.title\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0639\\u0646\\u0648\\u0627\\u0646 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"text\"],\"type\":\"text\",\"icon\":\"FileTextIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"bht9mrcgwuk\",\"table_alias\":\"18_42851\",\"column_alias\":\"18_42851_302444\",\"column_title\":\"18_42851.table_id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":{\"type\":{\"title\":\"Multi Select\",\"method\":\"multiSelect\"},\"table\":{\"id\":42868,\"database_id\":495,\"title\":\"tables\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u062c\\u062f\\u0627\\u0648\\u0644\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:43\",\"has_relation\":null},\"field\":{\"id\":302572,\"table_id\":42868,\"title\":\"title\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0646\\u0627\\u0645 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"data_type\":\"varchar(255)\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"0\",\"is_index\":\"0\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-23 15:19\"},\"fieldID\":{\"id\":302570,\"table_id\":42868,\"title\":\"id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647\",\"data_type\":\"bigint(20) unsigned\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"1\",\"is_index\":\"1\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:40\"},\"children\":{\"id\":\"s1d1zlfv3ym\",\"table_alias\":\"22_42865\",\"column_alias\":\"22_42865_302552\",\"column_title\":\"22_42865.source_column_id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":{\"type\":{\"title\":\"Multi Select\",\"method\":\"multiSelect\"},\"table\":{\"id\":42851,\"database_id\":495,\"title\":\"columns\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:43\",\"has_relation\":null},\"field\":{\"id\":302445,\"table_id\":42851,\"title\":\"title\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0639\\u0646\\u0648\\u0627\\u0646 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"data_type\":\"varchar(255)\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"0\",\"is_index\":\"0\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-24 10:32\"},\"fieldID\":{\"id\":302443,\"table_id\":42851,\"title\":\"id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"data_type\":\"bigint(20) unsigned\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"1\",\"is_index\":\"1\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:39\"}},\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"},\"haveFilter\":true},\"ForeignKey\":{\"id\":302444,\"table_id\":42851,\"title\":\"table_id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u062c\\u062f\\u0648\\u0644\",\"data_type\":\"bigint(20) unsigned\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"0\",\"is_index\":\"1\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:39\"}},\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"},\"haveFilter\":true},{\"id\":\"n5oh7twwav\",\"table_alias\":\"18_42851\",\"column_alias\":\"18_42851_302443\",\"column_title\":\"18_42851.id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":[],\"convertMethod\":{\"title\":\"No conversion\",\"type\":null},\"displayMode\":{\"title\":\"Right-Align\"}},{\"id\":\"s1d1zlfv3ym\",\"table_alias\":\"22_42865\",\"column_alias\":\"22_42865_302552\",\"column_title\":\"22_42865.source_column_id\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0634\\u0646\\u0627\\u0633\\u0647 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"tags\":[\"table\",\"\\u0631\\u0648\\u0627\\u0628\\u0637\",\"numeric\"],\"type\":\"numeric\",\"icon\":\"DivideSquareIcon\",\"isSelected\":true,\"filter\":{\"type\":{\"title\":\"Multi Select\",\"method\":\"multiSelect\"},\"table\":{\"id\":42851,\"database_id\":495,\"title\":\"columns\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646 \\u0647\\u0627\",\"type\":\"0\",\"ignore\":\"0\",\"updated_at\":\"1400-12-14 11:43\",\"has_relation\":null},\"field\":{\"id\":302445,\"table_id\":42851,\"title\":\"title\",\"alternative_title\":\"\\u0639\\u0646\\u0648\\u0627\\u0646 \\u0633\\u062a\\u0648\\u0646\",\"data_type\":\"varchar(255)\",\"default\":null,\"is_key\":\"0\",\"
```

**My mutation:**

```
    "Add A Report"
    createReport(

        "Input for report fields"
        input:reportsInput! @spread

    ): Report @create
```

**My input:**

```
"Input for report fields"
input reportsInput{

    "This field defines the title to describe this type"
    name: String!

    "Specifies report of data"
    data: String

    "Specifies the report belongs to which category id"
    report_category_id: Int!

    "Specifies the report belongs to which database id"
    database_id: Int!

}
```

Lighthouse version is: 5.41

thanks.

Comment: have you tried to use ' instead of " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve my problem!

My problem was with my playground.

I was using the suggested playground graphql and i understood my problem was with it.

If you have this problem use: **Firecamp** playground